Uniqueness of Hessenberg matrix in Cholesky factorization of Hankel matrix
I'm reading the paper how bad are Hankel matrices?, where the author claimed the following:

Lemma 2.1. For any positive definite Hankel matrix $H \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ there exist a Vandermonde matrix $V \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and a diagonal $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that
$$
H=V \Lambda^2 V^{\mathrm{T}} .
$$


Proof. Since $H$ is positive definite, we may consider the Cholesky decomposition of it:
$$
H=R^{\mathrm{T}} R,
$$
where $R \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is upper triangular. Following [4], we are now going to find an upper Hessenberg matrix $T$ such that
$$
r_{11}^{-1} R=\left[e_1, T e_1, \ldots, T^{n-1} e_1\right], \tag{2.4}
$$
where $e_1=[1,0, \ldots, 0]^{\mathrm{T}}$. It is evident that all $T$ 's columns, save for the last one, are uniquely determined from (2.4). The last column can be arbitrary, and we take it such that
$$
T e_n=T^{\mathrm{T}} e_n,
$$
....

The author stated that it is evident that all $T's$ columns, save for the last one, are uniquely determined from (2.4), but I have no idea why that is the case. I also don't understand why the last column can be arbitrary.
Perhaps this is due to some special property of powers of the Hessenberg matrix?

I would assume the upper Hessenberg matrix here is unreduced, i.e. the subdiagonal entries are all nonzero.

The first column of $T$ is of course $Te_1$, and so is determined by (2.4).
If $T$ is unreduced, upper Hessenberg matrix, then
$$Te_1 = a e_1 + be_2$$
for some $a, b$, with $b \neq 0$ (due to unreducedness). Hence
$$T^2 e_1 = a Te_1 + b Te_2 \Rightarrow Te_2 = \frac{1}{b} (T^2 e_1 - a Te_1).$$
Since (2.4) pinned down $T^2 e_1$ and $Te_1$ (hence $b$, the second entry of $Te_1$), we see that $Te_2$ is pinned down as well; i.e. the second column of $T$ is pinned down.

You can iterate this argument to see that for $i = 1, \cdots, n-1$, the $i$-th column of $T$ (i.e. $Te_i$) is pinned down by $Te_1, \cdots, T^i e_1$ recursively.
Finally, the above argument also shows that
$$span(Te_1, \cdots, T^{n-1}e_1) = span(Te_1, \cdots, Te_{n-1}).$$
In particular, the information of $Te_1, \cdots, T^{n-1}e_1$ does not constrain on the $n$-th column of $T$. The upper Hessenberg property does not impose extra constraint on this last column either; so the last column can be arbitrary.
